# Procedure Algorithm in Latex

Tags: algorithms

I would like to create an algorithm as follows.

[image]

The code in latex is as follows.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Sequence}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Procedure{Step I}
    \State Do $U_LL$ 
    \If{$n$ is odd number:}
        \State Do $U_n$
    \ELSE
        \STATE Do $L_n$
    \ENDIF
\Procedure{Step II}
    \State For $\(i=1,\ldots,n:\)$ 
    \If{$i \pmod{2}==1:$}
        \State Do $L_i$
    \ELSE
        \STATE Do $U_i$
    \ENDIF
\Procedure{Step III}
    \State For \(i=1,\ldots,(n-1)\) 
    \If{$i \pmod{2}==1:$}
        \State Do $U_i$
    \ELSE
        \STATE Do $L_i$
    \ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

However the code does not work. Could anyone help me, please?

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you mingle two packages?

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\floatplacement{algorithm}{tbp}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algorithmname}{\ALG@name}
\renewcommand{\floatc@ruled}[2]{{\@fs@cfont #1} #2\par}
\makeatother
\usepackage[commentColor=black]{algpseudocodex}
\tikzset{algpxIndentLine/.style={draw=black}}
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\bfseries\footnotesize #1}
\algrenewcommand{\textproc}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{Sequence}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Step I}{}
\State Do $U_LL$
\If{$n$ is odd number}
\State Do $U_n$
\Else
\State Do $L_n$
\EndIf
\EndProcedure
\Procedure{Step II}{}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n$}
\If{$i\bmod{2}==1$}
\State Do $L_i$
\Else
\State Do $U_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
\Procedure{Step III}{}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n-1$}
\If{$i\bmod{2}==1$}
\State Do $U_i$
\Else
\State Do $L_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\newpage
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{Sequence}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex \textbf{Step I}
\State Do $U_LL$
\If{$n$ is odd number}
\State Do $U_n$
\Else
\State Do $L_n$
\EndIf
\Statex \textbf{Step II}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n$}
\If{$i\bmod{2}==1$}
\State Do $L_i$
\Else
\State Do $U_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\Statex \textbf{Step III}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n-1$}
\If{$i\bmod{2}==1$}
\State Do $U_i$
\Else
\State Do $L_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @clara, when I applied the given code, the result is on 1 liner. I provided in the question page, thank you.

Comment: @NicholasTI Work well on TeX Live 2022. You can try it on Overleaf. If there is no problem, you need to update your TeX Live.

Comment: Hi @clara, noted. By the way, is there any way to delete the black line in the printed algorithm? Thank you.

Comment: @NicholasTI I have answered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676987