# Delete Index and Line in Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I would like to ask you is it possible to:

(1) delete the index on the left side and one at the last line (all 0's , yellow highlighted) ?

(2) delete all the line inside the algorithm ( green highlighted) ?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[commentColor=black]{algpseudocodex}

\floatplacement{algorithm}{tbp}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algorithmname}{\ALG@name}
\renewcommand{\floatc@ruled}[2]{{\@fs@cfont #1} #2\par}
\makeatother
\tikzset{algpxIndentLine/.style={draw=black}}
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\bfseries\footnotesize #1}
\algrenewcommand{\textproc}{\bfseries}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{Sequence}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex \textbf{Step I}
\State Do $U_{LL}$
\If{$n$ is odd number}
\State Do $U_n$
\Else
\State Do $L_n$
\EndIf
\Statex \textbf{Step II}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n$}
\If{$i\bmod{2}==1$}
\State Do $L_i$
\Else
\State Do $U_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\Statex \textbf{Step III}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n-1$}
\If{$i\bmod{2}==1$}
\State Do $U_i$
\Else
\State Do $L_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\State Do $L_{LL}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't compile. Please add the instructions needed to make it compilable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\floatplacement{algorithm}{tbp}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\floatc@ruled}[2]{{\@fs@cfont #1} #2\par}
\makeatother

\usepackage[commentColor=black,noEnd=false,indLines=false]{algpseudocodex}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Sequence}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Statex \textbf{Step I}
\State Do $U_{LL}$
\If{$n$ is odd number}
\State Do $U_n$
\Else
\State Do $L_n$
\EndIf
\Statex \textbf{Step II}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n$}
\If{$i\bmod{2}==1$}
\State Do $L_i$
\Else
\State Do $U_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\Statex \textbf{Step III}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n-1$}
\If{$i\bmod{2}==1$}
\State Do $U_i$
\Else
\State Do $L_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\State Do $L_{LL}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Clara, could you tell me what is the syntax for deleting all the 0's (index), please? Thank you.

Comment: @NicholasTI The option behind on `\begin{algorithmic}`, such as `\begin{algorithmic}[0]`. The default is `0`. You should read the doc of `algpseudocodex`.

Comment: Hi @clara, yes, I tried 

\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[commentColor=black, indLines=false]{algpseudocodex}


\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}

However, the index 0 all is still there. I am not sure what happened.

Comment: @NicholasTI You can directly run the code in my answer on TeX Live 2022.

Comment: yes, I use the same code as provided except the \usepackage[commentColor=black, indLines=false]{algpseudocodex} and run on TeX Live 2022. The black line is gone, however the index 0 is still there. Should I open a new question?

Comment: @NicholasTI I suggest you try it on overleaf. It is working. May be the tex live on your computer is broken.

Comment: Hi @clara, what I meant is I used overleaf with TeX Live 2022.

Comment: You can share your project. But I tested it and found no errors or warnings

Comment: Hi @clara, I posted all the preamble code here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678092/288908

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the useless redefinitions, which are essentially restating the default.

If you don't want the indent guides, specify the relevant option.

I don't get zeros, however, but the line numbers, so you might have something else in your document that makes the wrong numbering.

If you don't want line numbers, don't specify `[1]` after `\begin{algorithmic}`, as shown in the second example.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[
  commentColor=black,
  indLines=false,
]{algpseudocodex}

\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\bfseries\footnotesize #1}
\algrenewcommand{\textproc}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Sequence (with line numbers)}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex \textbf{Step I}
\State Do $U_{LL}$
\If{$n$ is odd number}
\State Do $U_n$
\Else
\State Do $L_n$
\EndIf
\Statex \textbf{Step II}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n$}
\If{$i\bmod{2}==1$}
\State Do $L_i$
\Else
\State Do $U_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\Statex \textbf{Step III}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n-1$}
\If{$i\bmod 2==1$}
\State Do $U_i$
\Else
\State Do $L_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\State Do $L_{LL}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\newpage

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Sequence (without line numbers)}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Statex \textbf{Step I}
\State Do $U_{LL}$
\If{$n$ is odd number}
\State Do $U_n$
\Else
\State Do $L_n$
\EndIf
\Statex \textbf{Step II}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n$}
\If{$i\bmod 2==1$}
\State Do $L_i$
\Else
\State Do $U_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\Statex \textbf{Step III}
\For{$i=1,\ldots,n-1$}
\If{$i\bmod{2}==1$}
\State Do $U_i$
\Else
\State Do $L_i$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\State Do $L_{LL}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

[image]